How to understand Giraud's axioms for a category to be topos?
I am a newbie in topos theory, and recently I met with the Giraud's axioms for a category $C$ to become the category of sheaves of sets on a Grothendieck site.
The Giraud's axioms include:
(a). the category $C$ is presentable ($C$ admits small limits and has a small set o generators)
(b). colimits in $C$ are universal.
(c). coproducts in $C$ are disjoint.
(d). equivalence relations are effective.
These axioms must correspond to some properties of category of sheaves on a site, and they are some 'key features' of topos so if a category satisfies these axioms, it must be a category of sheaves on certain site. I can understand that axiom (a) provides a collection of small generators, which become a small category where we can have sheaf on them. Axiom (b) corresponds to the 'pullback property' of the sheaf. But what about axiom (c) and (d), what are the features of a topos they correspond to?

I'm not quite clear: are you asking why a category of sheaves of sets on a Grothendieck site satisfies those conditions?  Or are you asking why those conditions make it looks like a category of sheaves of sets on a Grothendieck site, in which case the proof of Giraud's theorem will presumably show how those conditions are used in showing the desired equivalence of categories.

@DanielSchepler Yes! I am asking why a category of sheaves of sets on a Grothendieck site should have these properties? Sorry for my ambiguity of expression.

OK, then my answer to (a) would be somewhat different from yours: it's the fact that ${ h_U }$ where $U$ ranges over the objects of the site forms a generating set, where $h_U$ is the sheaf of sets defined by $h_U(V) := \operatorname{Hom}(V, U)$ and restriction maps are induced by composition -- or maybe in the general case, it's just a presheaf and you have to take the sheafification.  The idea in either case being that $h_U$ represents the functor of taking sections over $U$, so from $\operatorname{Hom}(h_U, \mathscr{F})$ you can recover $\mathscr{F}$ up to isomorphism.

@DanielSchepler Very great answer, thanks!

@DanielSchepler So the conditions for the generator correspond to the sheaf conditions and thus generators are  exactly the objects after the sheafification, right?
